# Won't submit login details

Tags: html, authentication

I'm trying to get our login portal working, but for some reason it won't accept the login details. It just won't submit the information, it just refreshes the page.

Any ideas would be extremely appreciated on how to fix this.

Many thanks!

```
 <div id="nav">

        <ul>
                <li id="login">
                        <a id="login-trigger" href="#">
                                Log In <span>▼</span>
                        </a>
                         <div id="login-content">
                                <form>
                                <form action="https://na6.salesforce.com/secur/login_portal.jsp" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="00D80000000anEa" name="orgId">
    <input type="hidden" value="060800000006ANB" name="portalId">
    <input type="hidden" value="true" name="useSecure">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="loginType">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="loginAction">
                                <fieldset id="inputs">
            <input id="txtUserIdGutter" class="InputText" type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Your email address" required>

            <input id="txtPasswordGutter" class="InputText" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                 </fieldset>
                                 <fieldset id="actions">
                                 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
                                                <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Keep me signed in</label>
                                                <label><a href="https://na6.salesforce.com/secur/forgotpasswordp.jsp?orgId=00D80000000anEa&amp;portalId=060800000006ANB&amp;pLu=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.carrierstore.com%2F">Forgot Password?</a></label>
                                        </fieldset>
                                </form>
                        </div>
                </li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page refreshes, it's supposed to hit your code behind. 
Do you have a log line or a breakpoint that you expect your code to be called?

Also, you have double form tags:

```
<form><form action="https://na6.salesforce....
```

Try to remove the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Take out your extra `<form>` tag.

```
                            <div id="login-content">
<!-- Remove this line: -->     <form>
                               <form action="https://na6.salesforce.com/secur/login_portal.jsp" method="POST">
```

Comment: Could you highlight this for me?

Thanks!

Comment: You guys are awesome. A simple little thing like this fixed it.

THANKS!

Comment: @user1459346 Since you're new here, here's a friendly reminder not to forget to [upvote/accept answers that solve your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/158402) `:)`